# How you know this file, this permission, this ower, this group?

Tags: permissions

I have some server where I completely messed up the permission with some `chmod -R`

I'm looking for a better user permission management.
I'm on windows, and I have to manage 4 different servers with ubuntu 14, 16.

I have learn about usermod/gpasswd and acl.
But now I don't know for each file, what should be the permission/group/owner on it?

**How you, adminsys are doing to know each time: this file/folder should belong to this group, this user ...?**
Do you have a Gnu/Linux clone which allow you to check how it should be? Or is there some general rules about it?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Are these system files, that you messed up?

Comment: I already solve most of the critical issue, but it certainly remain some wrong permission which could be a security issue.
That's why my question .

Answer (score 0):

If you messed up system files then a re-install is the quickest. To avoid this in the future, then use configuration management techniques (Note I said configuration management. Not revision control. However revision control is often part of configuration management).

Comment: I already solve most of the critical issue, but it certainly remain some wrong permission which could be a security issue. That's why my question

Comment: And do you have any link or document concerning these : "configuration management techniques" 
It isn't just how to use the different command right ?

Comment: You can do it with scripts: that is as far as I have got (mostly). Then there are tools, ansible, cf-engine, etc. There are also things like docker (not a config-manager, but it is easier to do config-managment).